# Can the distribution of $Z=kX+(1-k)Y$ conditional on $X\geq Y$ be decomposed into the distributions of $(X,Y)$ uniquely?

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables that take values on interval $[0,1]$. Let $Z=kX+(1-k)Y$ where $0\leq k\leq 1$ is a known constant. Suppose the distribution of $Z$ conditional on $X\geq Y$ is given, namely $F_{Z|X\geq Y}$.

Can we uniquely recover the two component distributions for $X$ and $Y$? In other words, is there another pair of independent random variables on $[0,1]$, say $(X^*,Y^*)$, such that the conditional distribution of $kX^*+(1-k)Y^*$ given $X^*\geq Y^*$ is just $F_{Z|X\geq Y}$?

Comment: Motivation? Personal tries?

Comment: My problem is motivated by some examples in our daily life. For example, in a simplified stock trading scenario, $X$ represents the buyers' bids and $Y$ represents the sellers' asks. The distributions of bids and asks are of the researcher's interest. But they don't have the order book so that the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are unknown. But they can observe the transaction price $Z=kX+(1-k)Y$ if there is a transaction. The transaction only happens if $X\geq Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us rephrase the question (in the case $k=\frac12$, for simplicity), so that perhaps more readers understand what is asked.

For every PDFs $f$ and $g$ on the real line, consider the nonnegative real number $$\kappa(f,g)=\int_\mathbb R\int_{z/2}^\infty f(x)g(z-x)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dz,$$ and, assuming that $\kappa(f,g)\ne0$, the PDF $f\Diamond g$ defined by $$(f\Diamond g)(z)=\frac1{\kappa(f,g)}\int_{z/2}^\infty f(x)g(z-x)\,\mathrm dx.$$
Question: Does the PDF $f\Diamond g$ determine uniquely the PDFs $f$ and $g$? In other words, is the mapping $(f,g)\mapsto f\Diamond g$ injective, where $f$ and $g$ are PDFs?